# How to use compiled erlang modules in an elixir project?

Tags: erlang, elixir, beam

I have an erlang application that has been compiled already so I do not have access to the source code.
The folder structure looks like this

```
base_app
  lib
    package_1
      ebin
        - package_1.app
        - package_1.beam
      src
        - package_1.app.src
    package_2
      ebin
        - package_2.app
        - package_2.beam
      src
        - package_1.app.src
```

I want to be able to call functions from those packages in my elixir code, for example

`:package_1.do_this()`

I have added those folders under the `lib` folder of my mix project, but that doesn't work for me. I'm unsure how else to go about this.

Answer (score -1):

When Elixir code is compiled, the generated `*.beam` files will live inside `_build/test|dev/*/ebin/`, its organized based on environment.

Hence in your case placing the compiled erlang code inside `lib` will not likely work. I haven't tried it myself, but try putting the compiled erlang folder somewhere in the `_build`(remember about environment) and then do some adjustments. I am not fully sure if this will work directly as `mix` is also involved.

Hope that helps!